# Flex : removeEventListener safely?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How to call `removeEventListener` when I don't know the function which is the event handler?

Comment: May I ask you, what for do you need such a feature? What is the use case?

Comment: I need to use only 1 even handler at once trought only 1 mothood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own implementation of EventDispatcher. It's sad but native IEventListener prototype doesn't provide lots usefull methods.

There is a sample code of how that implementation would look like:

```
package {
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

/**
 * Advanced Event Dispatcher with a ability to remove all listener by event type
 * @author  Rytis Alekna
 */
public class AdvancedEventDispatcher extends EventDispatcher {

    /** This var holds all references to listeners */
    protected var eventListenersByType : Dictionary = new Dictionary( true );

    /**
     * Call this method to remove all listeners of specified type
     */
    public function removeEventListenersByEventType ( type : String, useCapture : Boolean = false ) : void {

        var key : String = type + ":" + useCapture;

        if ( this.eventListenersByType[ key ] && this.eventListenersByType[ key ].lenght > 0 ) {

            // copy array of event listeners
            var listenersToRemove : Array = this.eventListenersByType[ key ].concat();

            // and clear original 
            this.eventListenersByType[ key ] = [];

            // loop over all listeners
            for ( var i : int = 0; i < listenersToRemove.length; i++ ) {
                this.removeEventListener( type, ( removeEventListenersByEventType[i] as Function ), useCapture );
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Override this method to implement listeners registration by type.
     */
    override public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false) : void  {

        // register with native method
        super.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);

        // create a key for storage
        var key : String = type + ":" + useCapture;

        // check if it doesn't already exist
        if ( !this.eventListenersByType[ key ] ) {
            this.eventListenersByType[ key ] = [];
        }

        // push listener to our storage
        this.eventListenersByType[ key ].push( listener );

    }

}
```

}

Otherwise as you mentioned that in your case you need to fire event only once than you can use such a handy framework like AS3 Signals (http://johnlindquist.com/2010/01/21/as3-signals-tutorial/)

Comment: I am unsure why you are doing this `if ( !this.eventListenersByType[ key ] )` since the line above, you are making a "Brand New Instance" of an annomanous object.. So there is NO WAY it could already be in Dictionary. Even if you called it twice with identical `type` and `useCapture` you would find its creating a new array in there each time. For this type of function I would recommend a different approach but if you were really set on doing it this way, you would need a "for in" loop on the dictionary to find a key with the properties that match and push into that key's value.

Comment: @WORMSS Thank you for correction. I forgot about that Object is no so primitive and is passed by reference. For this example the best way would be to serialize arguments to a string like "someEventType:false" and then use as a key.

Comment: Good call, I never thought of that approach.. I like strongly typed things too much. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function( event :Event ):void
{
     obj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, arguments.callee );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to remove all the other event handlers and add one yours. It's not possible, AFAIK. And it's very wierd behavior imho, since your goal is to have only one event listener - I'd better prevent rather than clean.

Consider using `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation` functions or custom class with logick you need (for instance, something with callbacks instead of events).

Comment: there is anonimous functions spam this event. It is like thousends per minute. This is not an option.

Comment: Then don't use anonimous functions - they lead to memory leaks almost every time.

Comment: at the current project - i cant find another way than using anonimous functions... which is actualy not anonimouse but exchangeing each other... :|

Comment: @Yordan Yanakiev You should never use unanimous functions never ever ever..... It is such a bad coding practice and has lots of management issues. Lazy coding gets you in trouble. This is AS3 not AS2 learn OOP and make a class that handles your needs.

Comment: I'd take issue with the idea that there's no reason to ever use anonymous functions.  Quite probably the OP does not have enough experience to use them without the management issues, but they're like anything else--they have their place if used appropriately.  For more information on using function references of all types, including anonymous ones, check out http://www.developria.com/2010/12/functional-actionscript-part-1.html